# Есть ли ошибки в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, лексика

*Вы сомневаетесь в эффективности продвижения вашей кампании или что это не принесет вам дохода?*

Есть ошибка в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1):

К**а**мпания может быть по продвижению чего-то, а продвигать можно к**о**мпанию.

> *...или что это не принесёт вам дохода?*

Если кто-то сомневается, что что-то не принесёт ему дохода, значит, он думает: а вдруг всё-таки оно принесёт доход, но, скорее всего, нет. Вы же, похоже, имеете в виду обратное: *вы сомневаетесь, что это принесёт доход.* То есть надеетесь, что принесёт, но нет полной уверенности.

Перед частью про доход надо добавить "в том" (иначе только
как разговорный вариант он с натяжкой годится) — тогда и для деловой переписки, возможно, подойдёт:

> Вы сомневаетесь в эффективности продвижения вашей компании или в том, что это принесёт вам доход?

Comment: Спасибо, а в остальном? считается ли такое предложение возможным для деловой переписки?

Comment: Едва ли, очень корявое.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.